# How to highlight as object in the 3d View/Outliner?

Tags: python, 3d-view, outliner

In a script of mine I want to make an object stand out among the others in the 3D View, so that the user can see which object are affected by it.

I'm open to suggestions, but I was thinking about:

- Change the highlight color of the object (like when objects in groups were green) in the 3D View
- Change the background color or the Text color of the object's name in the Outliner

Comment: You can always use x-ray in the object panel

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what the object panel looks like on the right, in the display section you'll find the option i'm talking about

Comment: No, that's not what I want: wireframe can be messy for complex objects and the user may want the object to be solid, and the object color doesn't work in Blender 2.8. I wanted something more customizable and so that you can easily distinguish the affected objects